# How do I replace this text with Regex?

Tags: regex

The tutorials for regex on the internet absolutely suck and I am struggling to do something simple.

I'm using foxreplace to try to replace some code on a website.

Here is an example of the line I want to replace

```
kalkomey.course.init(700083989,
              "/canada/course_content/course/101199/section/700083990?token=4c07deae80de88c6ec363618c6f19f6a",
              750,
              20,
              0, '', ''
          );
```

^That's exactly how it appears so I don't know if regex needs to define spaces or whitespace or whatever.

All I want to do is replace the "20" with 1.  That line could change completely except it should always start with `kalkomey.course.init(" and end with ");`  It should always have the same number of parameters separated by commas.

The code is for a stupid timer that won't allow you to go to the next page until the timer runs out.  In this case, the timer would be 20 seconds.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For a start, see the [regex tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) for how to improve your question. Yours is the only mention of "foxreplace" in this site; can you add a link or summary of its features?

Comment: I don't think a list or summary of it's features exists.  It works well but there is no literature.  It's an addin for firefox.  Basically, what it does is when a website loads it goes through the code and will replace stuff that you specify based on a find and replace.  I just found out that it will search and replace with regex but it doesn't mention what flavour of regex and the regex is ridiculously difficult to use.

Comment: So, this one; https://code.google.com/p/foxreplace/

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle strings, this can get a little tricky:

```
kalkomey\.course\.init\([\S\s]*?,[\S\s]*?(["'])((?:(?=(?:(\\))*)\3.|.)*?)\1[\S\s]*?,[\S\s]*?,[\S\s]*?(\d+?),
```

The text will be in capture group 4.

## [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wW3fW2/3)

You haven't provided a language so I can't provide you with code describing it's use.

Comment: I honestly don't know what language it uses.  The documentation for ForReplace is nonexistent.  I'm assuming javascript?

Wow, is it just me or is regex needlessly complicated?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @wallybanger I've looked up fox replace an I think this regex should work fine, assuming it's a browser extension, it probably does use JavaScript

Comment: I think I can see what you've done there.  The *? sets the search string as a numbered result, right?  So then in the replace field would I put in something like:
kalkomey\.course\.init\(\1,\2,\3,1,\5,\6,\7);

Correct?

And yes, FoxReplace is a browser extension.

Comment: @wallybanger the `*?` is just like `*` but non-greedy it's actually pretty complicated, especially the string part

Comment: Ok, so if I put ^that^ in the "replace" box, what do I put in the "with" box?

Comment: If you want to use part of the match as the replacement, you can use a backreference. The answer suggests `\4` to put the text which matched the fourth parenthesized subexpression as the replavement.

Comment: The popularity and ubiquity of regex hints that it's just you. But yes, that is a fairly complex expression. It's a bit of a hammer/nail problem. A simpler technology would certainly get this particular job done, but then you'd lose the generality and versatility of regex, and besides, you'd end up with a metric oodle of specialized notations for different tasks.

Comment: Yes, I just don't know what the back reference relates to.  What defines a reference?  Is there a new reference any time there is a break in the regex code?  So in this case, a comma.  Does that comma break up the code and create a new reference?  Is the example I posted above correct?

I'm sure it is a good tool.  I'm just frustrated because it's complicated and the documentation sucks.